# Dividir o body em 4 partes de cores diferentes

Tags: css3

Teria como chegar ao resultado da imagem abaixo utilizando apenas **Css** no `body`?

> **Obs:** Sem usar **`divs`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Máximo que consegui:

```css
body{ 
  background: linear-gradient( to right, red 25%, green 25%, green 70%, yellow 70%, yellow 80%, blue 80%, blue );
}
```

Comment: Por que só com o `body`?

Comment: Quero este plano de fundo na tela inteira.

Comment: Vc quer só as 4 cores ou vc quer 4 containers?

Comment: Podeira usar `<div>`! Seria mais fácil e acredito eu, possível. Já com o `body` não sei se dá para fazer.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz Não posso usar `div` amigão para isto.

Comment: @hugocsl isso, só as 4 cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Opção 1

4 backgrounds com 1/4 do tamanho da tela e alinhados cada um em um cando com `background-position`

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image:
                    linear-gradient(#f00 0, #f00 100%),
                    linear-gradient(#ff0 0, #ff0 100%),
                    linear-gradient(#0f0 0, #0f0 100%),
                    linear-gradient(#00f 0, #00f 100%);
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-position: top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

## Opção 2

Exatamente com essas cores eu não consegui por causa do blend-mode das cores... mas deu para chegar em um resultado bem próximo...

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #f00 0, #f00 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%),
    linear-gradient(to right, #00f 0, #00f 50%, #ff0 50%, #ff0 100%);
    background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
        background-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

Comment: Show Hugo, valeu cara. Vou utilizar a primeira opção. Obrigado pelas duas respostas

Comment: @LeAndrade tranquilo jovem, na verdade eu tb usaria a primeira rss, só que eu fiquei tão frito com o `background-size` que não me dei conta que o `background-position` que era o caminho na verdade... Ei deixei as duas resposta... Boa sorte ai! tmj